# Ошибка при переходе на PHP 7 в CMS Bitrix 15

Tags: битрикс, php7

При переходе на PHP 7 Bitrix **15** версии после штатных настроек вылазит ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Bitrix\Main\Diag\ExceptionHandler::handleException() must be an
>   instance of Exception, instance of Error given in
>   bitrix/modules/main/lib/diag/exceptionhandler.php:167
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   Bitrix\Main\Diag\ExceptionHandler->handleException(Object(Error)) #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   bitrix/modules/main/lib/diag/exceptionhandler.php
>   on line 167

Как осуществить переход и исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Переход надо осуществлять путём обновления продукта до версии 16.5 и выше http://www.intervolga.ru/blog/support/1c-bitrix-with-php-7/

Answer (score -1):

Нет ни какого смысла описывать. Битрикс имеет очень много строк кода, многие из которых были написаны очень давно. И использовались функции, мелочи, которые в PHP7 не допустимы. В PHP7 было много серьезных изменений. Это потребовало дополнительные работы по обеспечению совместимости Битрикс и PHP 7. Как и сказали в перовом ответе: для перехода на PHP7 необходимо обновиться до, как минимум, 16.5 это для 7.0 если желаете PHP 7.1 то надо брать до актуальной версии.

Если обновиться нет возможности рекомендую остаться на версии PHP 5.6. Либо отрабатывать ошибку за ошибкой самостоятельно.

Дополнительно стоит обратить внимание на сторонние решения и модули (а так же код выполненный разработчиками конкретно вашего сайта) там так же может быть код не подходящий для PHP7.

Рекомендации при этом не зависят от Битрикс. Они стандартные для процедуры перехода с 5.x на 7.х

Comment: Думаю у вас слабое представление о том чем грозит использование старой версии php. Во вторых много строк кода обязывает писать манулы, или скрипты, чего кстати битрикс не написал в официальной документации за 3 года. А ман нужен. По факту это наплевательское отношение к продукту и к инжененому делу.

Comment: Ровно тем же грозит и использование старой версии любой CMS. Так что даже в этой плоскости совет прежний - обновляйтесь до свежей версии. Продлить битрикс будет дешевле, чем заплатить за работу по его доработки под PHP7.  Не надо заниматься кустарщиной. И уж если заниматься проектом серьезно то надо обновлять не только PHP. Уязвимости находят и в ядре линукс, и в битрикс.

Comment: Про мануал я не понял. Какого вам не хватает. Если по доработке Битрикс 15до php7. Ни кто такое в здравом уме не делал. А в компании Битрикс есть git репозиторий, но он не публичный. А мне, как разработчику, это не нужно. Свои решения я знаю как апгрейдить. Может я не так понял ваш вопрос? Итак какой вам мануал нужен?